# How can I find the file path of any function or what it contains in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, frontend, backend

When I do frontend development with PHP, I encounter statements similar to the following.

For example;

```
$this->getTheme()->getConfig('text_top', true);
```

For example, I want to find in which folder the "getConfig()" function is defined? Because I'm curious about the content? ie how the funtion is defined, what parameters it takes.

Is there a way to find this in php? Or it would be useful to see how the function is defined instead of the file path.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You don't have all files in a ide?

Comment: there is. But finding it is really hard work. I just wanted to ask if anyone knows an easy way. @SimoneRossaini

Comment: In my IDE (VSCode, but it works the same/similar in most common IDE's), I can simply control click on the method and it will open the correct file and show the code for the method. Can't see an easier way than that. Or hovering the mouse over it and it will show the method signature (what arguments it takes)

Comment: In all ide exist the method for "go to decleration", i use Netbeans and it's just right mouse on name of function -> "navigate" ->  "go to decleration"

Comment: At worst a grep or Ctrl+F in the IDE to search all files in the solution for getConfig. Then you just have to distinguish between calls to it and the definition of the function, which should be easy enough. But yeah if you have the IDE set up correctly as M.Eriksson mentions, it should help you and take you there directly.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Does this also happen with .php extension files? yes I'm using VSCode too and what you said works great for ".js" files only. but in my case it doesn't work on files with ".php" extension.